# Ingress Minimum Attack Efficiency

Tags: ingress

I was experimenting with the "hold fire" option to get the 20% bonus attack this morning and I was doing it with some level 1 bursters. Nearby high level resonators (7 & 8) reported damage as -1%

I thought it was interesting that such a high level portal was damaged by a level 1 burster, so I gave a level 6 burster a try with the max +20% bonus on the hold fire, but again I only got -1% damage

I didn't think about repeating it and checking the actual XM damage from each attack, but it made me question whether due to maximum mitigation, using a lower level burster would acheive the same damage as a higher level burster.

Does anyone have any evidence of this being the case?  I will experiment again but someone might already have the data available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if what you're seeing with different bursters is the same 1% animation, you're not actually doing the same damage. If you noticed, you'll never see decimal numbers when firing an XMP, so what's actually happening is that you're doing a different amount of damage with the two different bursters, but those are both going to show as 1% because that's the nearest integer percentage that rounds both the amounts (you'll never see 0% when attacking). If you want to see the actual amount of damage, check the logs next time you do an attack.

Comment: Makes perfect sense... can't believe I didn't see this logic previously!  This is confirmed with my experimentation yesterday too.